# Problem running sample Voice Recognition application on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run sample application VoiceRecognition on Android Emulator SDK 2.2. As i click on Speak button i get a pop - up "This application Voice Search (process com.google.android.voicesearch) has stopped unexpectedly ".
Can i know the why it happens and how to correct it?
I have been asking android questions but till date got no reply..

If anyone has worked or working on Voice Recognition please help me

Comment: Can you try running it on a device? Otherwise how do you intend to speak into the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Speech Recognition does not work in the Emulator.

You must have a device, and one that has a Speech Recognition provider installed.